# Source dump interrupted by computer restart

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm have a wamp server installed on my windows machine *(apache 2.4.9, mySQL 5.6, php 5.5, PHPmyAdmin 4.1)*. I was recently performing a source dump operation to restore a tables in a database. Previously I restored several large tables successfully to my database, but in the middle of the most recent operation, my machine decided to restart. <strike>Thanks windows update!</strike>

When the machine rebooted, I find that I am unable to connect to the server. The wamp symbol is orange instead of green and I have no access to get into mysql, PHPMyAdmin, or anything else.

I've tried restarting the wamp server but I have no success. I have also attempted to restart the machine several times to no avail. Does anyone know of how I could remedy this *(get a connection back to mySQL and/or my server)* without destroying the other successfully restored tables?

Comment: You need to locate mysql error log (might be somewhere in `C:\wamp\logs`) and get the error messages. You can add those to your question, either directly or using a pastebin service etc.